# Return multiple objects for a function that returns a Python Iterable object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples, iterable

Be the following dataframe:

| country_ID | ID | date | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ESP | 0 | 2022-01-02 | OUT |
| UK | 0 | 2022-01-05 | OUT |
| ESP | 1 | 2022-03-02 | IN |
| UK | 2 | 2022-02-05 | IN |
| UK | 2 | 2022-02-06 | OUT |
| ESP | 2 | 2022-02-10 | OUT |

```
import pandas as pd  
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

def function1(country_ID: str, date_old:pd.Timestamp, date_now:pd.Timestamp):
    town1, town2 = (0, 0)
    time_delta = pd.NaT
    flag = False
    if country_ID == 'ESP':
        time_delta = date_now-date_old
        flag = True
    else:
        town1 += 1
        town2 += 1

    return (town1, town2, time_delta), flag

def function2(country_ID: str, date_old:pd.Timestamp, date_now:pd.Timestamp):
    town1, town2 = (0, 0)
    time_delta = pd.NaT
    flag = False
    if country_ID == 'UK':
        time_delta = date_now-date_old
    else:
        town1 += 1

    return (town1, town2, time_delta), flag

def function_test(df):
    # Create tuples and extra rows
    new_rows = pd.DataFrame()
    direction = {
        ('IN', 'IN'): function1,
        ('OUT', 'OUT'): function1,
        ('IN', 'OUT'): function2,
        ('OUT', 'IN'): function2,
    }

    list_ids = []
    prev = None
    # Iterate on the complete dataset
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if row.ID not in list_ids:
            yield (2, 2, pd.NaT)
            list_ids.append(row.ID)
            prev = row
        else:
            conditional_func = (direction[(row.direction, prev.direction)])
            insert_row, flag = conditional_func(prev.country_ID, prev.date, row.date)
            if flag:
                new_rows = new_rows.append({'country_ID' : 'NEW' , 'date' : row.date, 'ID' : row.ID, 'direction':'OUT','visit_town1':0, 'visit_town2':0, 'visit_time':row.date-prev.date}, ignore_index=True)
            yield (insert_row)
            
            prev = row
            
    # Shows the newly constructed DataFrame correctly
    print(new_rows)
            
    return Iterable[Tuple[int,int,int,pd.Timestamp]], new_rows

def main():
# assign data of lists.  
    data = {'country_ID': ['ESP', 'UK', 'ESP', 'UK', 'UK', 'ESP'], 'ID': [0,0,1,2,2,2],
            'date': ['2022-01-02','2022-01-05','2022-03-02', '2022-02-05', '2022-02-06', '2022-02-10'],
            'direction': ['OUT','OUT','IN','IN','OUT','OUT']}  
  
    # Create DataFrame  
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
    
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    
    # It works correctly, but only returns the Iterable.
    # df[['visit_town1', 'visit_town2', 'visit_time']] = (tuple(function_test(df)))
    
    
    one, other = function_test(df)
    df[['visit_town1', 'visit_town2', 'visit_time']] = (tuple(one))
    print(other)
    
  
    # Print the output.  
    print(df)  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

Resulting DataFrame:

| country_ID | ID | date | direction | visit_town1 | visit_town2 | visit_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ESP | 0 | 2022-01-02 | OUT | 2 | 2 | NaT |
| UK | 0 | 2022-01-05 | OUT | 0 | 0 | 3 days |
| ESP | 1 | 2022-03-02 | IN | 2 | 2 | NaT |
| UK | 2 | 2022-02-05 | IN | 2 | 2 | NaT |
| UK | 2 | 2022-02-06 | OUT | 0 | 0 | 1 days |
| ESP | 2 | 2022-01-10 | OUT | 1 | 1 | NaT |

While Iterable is looping through the dataframe, I'm creating another dataframe called `new_rows`. The result of `print(new_rows)`, in this example would return the following result:

| country_ID | date | ID | direction | visit_town1 | visit_town2 | visit_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NEW | 2022-01-05 | 0 | OUT | 0 | 0 | 3 days |

The main problem is that I don't know how to return this new dataframe to main.

If I use the following code, I get an error on the screen:

```
one, other = function_test(df)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the values added to the new_rows DataFrame. I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: From a quick look, doesn't `function_test(df)` already return a tuple? Why are you doing this `(tuple(one))`? In any case, which line does the error message indicate?

Comment: @YannisP. ```one, other = function_test(df)  
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)``` Anyway, my problem is that I don't know how to return both DataFrames created in the function.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error by running your script but: 1) when you write `one, other = function_test(df)`, `test(df)` is not defined. Are you reading it in some previous _cell_ in Jupyter? 2) `list_ids.append(row.num_plate_ID)` throws of course an error, because _there is no such column_. Please edit your code appropriately.

Comment: @YannisP. Edited! You should be able to run the code now.

Comment: You should know that `yield` returns a value and makes the returned object work almost like generator. If you write something like `for r in function_test(df): print(r)` you will see that `function_test()`might behave somewhat unexpectedly, because you are yielding results

Comment: @YannisP. and how could I adapt the code to get both DataFrames efficiently? I don't care if ```yield``` is not used.

Comment: you can adapt by removing both `yield` statements, and then the code will return the `Iterable` and the `DataFrame`. The `DataFrame` gets some values that don't make some sense to me. I had to also write `df[['visit_town1', 'visit_town2', 'visit_time']] = one`, to start getting some results, otherwise this assignment did not work. I don't really think those comments helped, but your code is rather cryptic and you aren't saying what you want to do with it. I would suggest that you post your code in a forum, to see if you can get some more help.